# What is value of c, if c =a,b;

Tags: c

```
int a=0;
int b=1;
int c=a,b;
int d=(a,b);
```

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: See [Comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

Comment: If this is homework, I seriously have doubts about whatever school you're going to. Pack up and find another school that teaches more than the answers to stupid interview questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outside of an initialization, the comma in `a,b` is the *comma operator*, and evaluates to `b`.  The parentheses in the line involving `d` makes this such a case.  So that line is really just equivalent to:

```
int d = b;
```

However, in the line involving `c`, this is not a use of the comma operator.  Instead, it's just a list of variable definitions, equivalent to:

```
int c = a;
int b;
```

(Which consequently will not compile, due to redefinition of `b`!)

Comment: Only for `d`. For `c` it doesn't parse as the comma operator.

Comment: @Chris: Damn, that's a good point!  I hadn't noticed this was in an initialization!