# C programming question

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is value of c, if c =a,b;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950019/what-is-value-of-c-if-c-a-b)

How does the initialization of int variables work in the following question:

```
main()
{
   int i,j,k;
   i=1,2;
   j=(1,2);
   k=(1,2),(3,4);
}
```

I need to be able to describe what the compiler actually does.

Comment: Looks like a homework question. Why not figure it out for yourself?

Comment: Please lable as homework. In addition, you will find that you are more likely to get help if you show at least some attempt to find the answer yourself. We are are not here to do your work for you.

Comment: @Tim Post - "Poorly worded question" != "not real question." There is clearly a question here, and it can clearly be answered. It's probably a duplicate, and any question that mentions the comma operator will adequately address the answer, but "not a real question" is not a valid reason to close this.

Comment: @Chris, would you mind joining a short chat? I don't want to pollute this with a sidebar any more than we have. Or perhaps raise a meta question? You are sufficiently describing a technical dilemma that we often encounter.

Comment: @Tim - Let's do this. (I've never used SO chat before. How does it work?)

Comment: @Chris Just follow [this link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2563/room-for-chris-lutz-and-tim-post)

Answer (score 2):

comma is used as separator as well as an operator.
the three cases are dealt as below:
first: i=1,2; assignment has higher precedence to comma(,) so i=1 is evaluated i.e. i is given value 1 and then 2 is just put there without any use.
second: j=(1,2) parentheses has highest precedence so contents inside it will be evaluated first (1,2) will result to 2 and hence j is assigned value 2.
third: k=(1,2),(3,4); here (1,2) and (3,4) are evaluated to 2,4
and then it is like the first expression i.e. k=2,4 so k will be assigned value 2.

hope this helps :D

Comment: Nyc Explaination mrinal why dont you register up ? +1